# How get all matches using str.contains in python regex?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame, in which I need to find all the possible matches rows which match with `terms`. My code is

```
texts = ['foo abc', 'foobar xyz', 'xyz baz32', 'baz 45','fooz','bazzar','foo baz']
terms = ['foo','baz','foo baz']
# create df
df = pd.DataFrame({'Match_text': texts})
#cretae pattern 
pat = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(terms))
# use str.contains to find matchs
df = df[df['Match_text'].str.contains(pat)]

#create pattern
p = re.compile(pat)

#search for pattern in the column
results = [p.findall(text) for text in df.Match_text.tolist()]
df['results'] = results
```

The output is

```
Match_text  results
0   foo abc     [foo]
3   baz 45      [baz]
6   foo baz     [foo, baz]
```

In which, `foo baz` is also matching with row 6 along with `foo`, and `baz`. I need to get rows for all matches which are in the `terms`

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: I need one more row which matches `foo baz`  which is the row 6

Comment: Perhaps you want to use the regular expression `\b(?:foo baz|foo|baz)\b`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Sf3Qs/2/). Note that `foo baz` must be the first term in the alternation.

Comment: Yeah, your suggestion work @cary. But I can't assure sane pattern Everytime as it generates automatically.

Comment: @Raghu Try `pat = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(sorted(terms,key=len,reverse=True)))`, does it work for you? I am not sure what the final row result should be, `[foo baz]` or `[foo, baz, foo baz]`? I have a solution for both.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It works with `(sorted(terms,key=len,reverse=True))`. Is there any way to get the result without sorting, BCS I will lose stationarity of my data by sorting. .

Comment: @Raghu You cannot, because the longer alternatives should come before the shorter ones. This is done by sorting only.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, Understood. Then let me follow your method. Thanks for the solution and clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The longer alternatives should come before the shorter ones, thus, you need to sort the keywords by length in the descending order:

```
pat = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(sorted(terms,key=len,reverse=True)))
```

The result will be `\b(?:foo baz|foo|baz)\b` pattern. It will first try to match `foo baz`, then `foo`, then `baz`. If `foo baz` is found, the match is returned, then the next match is searched for from the end of the match, so you won't match `foo` or `baz` found with the previous match again.

See more on this in ["*Remember That The Regex Engine Is Eager*"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html#eager).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the regex pattern for checking the presence of terms,

```
#create pattern
p = re.compile(pat)

#search for pattern in the column
results = [p.findall(text) for text in df.Match_text.tolist()]
```

Try using a simple lookup of terms in the text like this.

```
#search for each term in the column
results = [[term for term in terms if term in text] for text in df.Match_text.tolist()]
```

Output for the above looks like this,

```
    Match_text  results
0   foo abc [foo]
3   baz 45  [baz]
6   foo baz [foo, baz, foo baz]
```

NOTE : There is a time complexity associated to this method.